# CSS class inside of class

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new in web development.

```
.chartBars {
   .bars {
      li {
      }
   }
}
```

Is this the same as this?

```
.chartBars {
}
.chartBars .bars {
}
.chartBars .bars li {
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hello, explained very briefly**

in css

```css
.chartBars { color: #000; }
.bars { color: #fff; }
li { color: #ccc; }

/* if 'bars' in 'chartBars', than color: #999; */

.chartBars .bars{ color: #999; }

/* if 'li' in 'bars', than color: #ccc; */

.bars li{ color: #ccc; }

/* if 'li' in 'bars' and 'bars' is in 'chartBars' color: #eee; */

.chartBars .bars li { color: #eee; }
```

in sass

```css
.chartBars { color: #000; }
.bars { color: #fff; }
li { color: #ccc; }

.bars {
 li { 
  color: #ccc;
 }
}

.chartBars {
  color: #000;

 .bars {
  color: #999;

  li {
   color: #eee;
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: The "`chartBars` contains `bars`" part of the logic is missing in your CSS example.

Answer (score 0):

No, the first example is not a valid CSS rule. To use nested CSS rules you would need to extend it using SCSS: https://sass-lang.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Sass, yes. If plain CSS, no. As for other CSS preprocessors, I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

Is it the same?
- It can be the same or not.
It is [CSS preprocessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/CSS_preprocessor)

First snippet is written as SCSS grammar.
So it is not normal CSS formatting, but you can say it is the same.
Because, if it is compiled, it will generate as the second snippet.

Here is an official link of style rules for SCSS
https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules#nesting

I think you better understand the basics of CSS first and then take a look at CSS preprocessor.

Comment: You would still need to know how you can use SCSS in your project.